# Rubymine shortcut to insert <%= %>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

Is there a shortcut for inserting a `<%= %>` in Rubymine?

I took a look in keymap and didn't see anything.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The default shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Period</kbd> on Windows and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Period</kbd> on Mac. It may not work on all the keyboards, in which case you can change it in `Settings` (`Preferences` on Mac) | `Keymap`: `Main Menu`, `Tools`, `Erb`, `Insert <%= %>`:

[image: keymap]

You can also use code completion:

[image: completion]

After accepting this choice you'll get:

```
<%= | %>
```

Another option is to define a live template:

[image: live template]

Type `re`, then <kbd>Tab</kbd> to expand.

Finally, you can define a keyboard shortcut for any text/template using the following trick:

1. `Edit` | `Macros` | `Start Macro Recording`
2. Type `re`, then <kbd>Tab</kbd>
3. `Edit` | `Macros` | `Stop Macro Recording`
4. Save it under `RubyExpression` name

Now go to `Keymap` settings and assign a shortcut to `RubyExpression` under `Edit`, `Macros`.

Comment: This is a phenomenal answer. Thank you for being so thorough.

Comment: @CrazyCoder can you take a look this please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21739483/rubymine-6-update-refresh-available-methods-and-paths-in-a-rails-project

Comment: @JohnWu make a copy as you can't modify the default keymap.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the plugin to make this work very 
easy. [link](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6184?pr=idea)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a shortcut or not, but usually you can just type in the first portion, and rubymine will auto close it. You just have to hit a space after you do the opening. So doing:

```
<%' ' outputs=> <% /code %>
<%=' ' outputs=> <%= /code %>
```

And it does this for the rest of the openings.

Answer (score 1):

I show it listed as Cmd-Shift-., but that's also mapped to folding. I remapped mine to Cmd-Shift-,.

(Plain IntelliJ; RubyMine may vary slightly.)

Comment: @TylerDeWitt See CrazyCoder's answer. I went into the keymap, narrowed on "erb", and there it was.

Answer (score 0):

1. `CMD ,` to open settings
2. Type **erb insert** to quickly find the keyboard shortcut for this task
3. Right-click `Insert '<%= =>` and click *Add Shortcut*
4. Enter a shortcut you prefer. I chose to use `ALT =`
5. Repeat for the other interpolation hotkey (`ALT`  → `<% %>`)
6. Hit **Apply**, then hit **OK**

[image: ruby on rails erb embed keyboard shortcut settings page]