# How to paste predefined code snippet in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

Is there way to define snippets in PyCharm, built-in or via plug-in? For example I want paste `self.` by hotkey. Now I'm doing it by `'se' + CTRL+ENTER`, but want to find more efficient way for this frequent operation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use macros for this purpose. Edit | Macros | Start Macro Recording begins the recording, then Settings | Keymap allows you to assign keyboard shortcuts to macros.

Comment: [Here is the detailed answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9639266/104891) showing how to assign a keyboard shortcut to the live template via macros.

Comment: Excellent! 'Works like a charm' :)

Answer (score 9):

What you are probably looking for is PyCharm's *live templates* - although for something as short as `self.` - they probably are no quicker than typing.

Comment: Yeah, I already discover it. Seems like their purpose to do more complex and less frequent job, like surround with `try:...except:`. And they cannot be bounded with a hotkey.

Comment: I'm not sure it makes sense to try and use a hotkey to insert something so short - it's not going to be quicker than typing it.

Comment: @GillBates, @Lattyware: Are you saying that pressing 2 keys instead of 5 is still "not so good solution"? Live template with `s` as abbreviation and `Tab` (my own preference) as expand key: and now `s[TAB]` magically transforms into `self.`

Comment: @LazyOne I'm not saying it's not shorter - I just don't really see it's that valuable - there are a few characters different, and hotkeys tend to break your flow in typing more than just typing it out.

Comment: @Lattyware. Hot key -- yes, 100% agree on that. Using Live Template for this (as per your answer) is a very valid choice here (because of the way how it works -- you naturally type/press 2 characters/keys one by one instead of pressing combination of keys (2 and more) at the same time). In short: I agree with your answer on using Live Templates over Hot Keys here even if result text (`self.`) is quite short especially if such text/construction is used a lot.

Comment: @LazyOne Well, it is matter of taste. I can counter with that, `sTAB ` takes longer time, than `ALT+s`, or `SHIFT+s`, because you need to hit two keys sequentially, and combo takes as much time as hitting one key takes. And also - `TAB` lies on the edge of keyboard, and `ALT`/`SHIFT` is almost always under fingers, which makes them more easy to access.

Comment: i agree, live templates work pretty well. eg i use them to type "ipdb<enter>" and it completes it to "import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()" for quick drop into debug shell anywhere... upboat.