# Rubymine 6 update/refresh available methods and paths in a rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

Here's an example. Say I update routes with `resources :foo` and that buys me some new paths like: `new_foo_session` When I begin to type the path in an ERB view I expect it to show me/ suggest with auto complete the names matching the path. So as I type: `new_foo_` I would get all the routes that match.

Also after installing a gem say `devise` which has helpers like `current_user` I would like RubyMine to suggest `current_user` as I begin to type it, however I am not getting that.

[image]

**How do I update the list of available helpers, methods, paths, etc in RubyMine 6 within my rails project to reflect in suggest/complete?**

Comment: I can confirm you the behaviour, I still don't know why it doesn't work though.

Comment: @lucke84 by confirm do you mean that you are experiencing the same as me or that you are getting the proper working behavior?

Comment: Experiencing the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spoke to rubymine support. This feature is not available for gems.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just restart the IDE.